Is there a better way to reinforce this zip tie through this plastic to ensure the plastic won’t tear?
I put pieces of packing tape over it before puncturing it.
Img here: https://imgur.com/9sB2A4u

There may be better ways but you won't get useful answers unless you describe what you are trying to achieve, and when and why your existing solution fails.  It's possible your solution is perfectly adequate, or overkill, or useless. ... Depending on the goal.

imgur not working please add the picture to the question

Cannot make out exactly what you are doing in the picture, but rolling the edge of the plastic a few times around a wood/metal dowel will increase the amount of force needed to rip out.

There's not enough information to help here. I can't even tell what I'm looking at in that photo.

Layer up on the plastic and then add a strip or two of duct tape. Crimp a metal eyelet through the material. Nothing will really ensure it won't tear but this will help.
